# JAXB annotations with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, jaxb

I'm trying to retrieve an XML which has this format:

```
<roles>
 <role>manager</role>
 <role>driver</role>
</roles>
```

I use this classes and annotations:

```
public class Clazz(){

   private Role roles;

   get/set

}

public class Role (){

   private String role;

   get/set
}
```

With this annotations i'm able to retrieve only the first role, i.e.:

```
 <roles>
   <role>driver</role>
 </roles>
```

What should i change in order to take and the other role? The number of the role is not standard, sometimes could be one, other two and other 3.

Comment: What about `private List<String> role`?

Comment: It was very easy, i should think about it.Thank you anyway.

Comment: yes it was your comment correct solution.add it to mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@XmlElement
private List<String> role;
```

Note that you have several `<role>` nodes so obviously you need a collection to hold all of them.